# after you havING viewed VS after you have viewed / after having viewed -- is this a special case here?

Tags: grammar, verbs

1. ...after you have viewed the document, we could continue our conversation
2. ...after having viewed the document, we...
3. ...after you hav**ing** viewed the document, we...

I am aware that number 1 and 2 are correct. I am also aware of the difference in meaning/when to use.

My question: Is number 3 correct / accepted?

I believe I have heard such constructions in British English, e.g. ***"after him having viewed the document, we..."*** but I need certainty.

What is the grammatical term for number 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. (3) is OK. Using the accusative or objective pronouns *me, you, him, us, them*, followed by a gerund form (in this case 'after **you** having viewed') is often dismissed as 'incorrect' by traditional grammarians. It is, however, so commonly used that most people regard it as a less formal variant of the more 'correct' or 'educated' form using a possessive, *my, your, his, our, their*, 'after **your** having viewed...' (*Her* is the same in both variants).

Comment: This might be different in BrE and AmE. As an American, I rarely hear "after you having viewed" and it sounds "off" to me somehow.

Comment: @Esther - well, in BrE, 'after you having viewed' comes over as less 'stuffy' than ''after your having viewed'. Chapter 14, section 4.3, of the Cambridge Grammar of the English Language, has a section seeking to destroy the traditional distinction between gerund clauses and present participle clauses, by arguing they all belong to a single inflectional category; namely, gerund-participles.

Comment: I was going to add that I would use "your" only in formal contexts, and option 1 (after you have viewed" in other ones, but I guess that part didn't get into the comment ;) It is "stuffy" in AmE as well, but "you" here seems less common than you describe.

Answer (score -2):

Actually, it's number **1** and **3** which are correct.

**...after having viewed the document, we...** would mean:

After **we** have viewed the document...

Comment: #2 is definitely correct, e.g. "We talked, and after having viewed the document ( i.e. after viewing the document), we meet and speak about the unclear parts."

Comment: @johann_ka. Generally speaking, yes, it is correct, but in the specific sense mentioned here, I don't think it is. And I have explained why in my answer.

Comment: Your answer assumes  that the person speaking also hasn't yet read it. That doesn't seem a likely conclusion.